# How to remove empty words from my SQL string_to_array?

Tags: postgresql

I have a text column in my Postgres table and I want to remove any non-alphabetical characters and split it by a space (so I can use each word to do a search later).

I can remove the characters and split it successfully however my rows have empty results. I cannot have any empty words:

```sql
SELECT
    asset.id,
    string_to_array(TRIM(regexp_replace(asset.title, '[^a-zA-Z ]', '', 'g')), ' ')
FROM
    assets asset
```

eg.
`Hello world!` becomes `{Hello,world}`
but also `Some Result V1.0 - 3D Model` becomes `{Some,Result,V,,D,Model`

How do I filter my array to remove empty words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform array to table, then clean the content, and transform result to array again:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.remove_empty_string(text[])
 RETURNS text[]
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
select array(select v from unnest($1) g(v) where v <> '')
$function$

(2022-06-20 05:17:57) postgres=# select remove_empty_string(array['Some','Result','V','','D','Model']);
┌─────────────────────────┐
│   remove_empty_string   │
╞═════════════════════════╡
│ {Some,Result,V,D,Model} │
└─────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: (Scratch last comment) This works the best as it guarantees you do not get empty items in the final array. I did have to change the return type to `TEXT[]` though

Comment: @Jared - yes, there was a bug, fixed

Answer (score 1):

#### Try using a multicharacter regular expression

Try with this:

```
SELECT
    asset.id,
    string_to_array(TRIM(regexp_replace(asset.title, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', 'g')), ' ')
FROM
    assets asset
```

I just removed the whitespace from the regex in order to capture every non-alphabet character. Then, the + indicates one or more coincidences, which ensures than any consecutive non-alphabetical character will get replaced with a single space. Finally, as you already do the trim, your split by whitespace will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I combined yours with the accepted one as I still had empty strings inside my array.

Comment: @Jared Your welcome. I'm glad it worked at least partially for you.